# Launch map app on mobile device with multiple destinations

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, apple-maps

I'm looking to launch the native map app on iOS, Android and Windows Phone devices with multiple destinations shown in the directions.

Sending basic directions works fine using Google and Apple maps daddr but from what I can there's no way to specify multiple destinations using the map link (example below).

```
https://www.google.com/maps?daddr=LAT,LONG
```

I've also tried using a URL to load the desktop version of Google maps (which asks if the user wants to open the app anyway) but multiple destinations doesn't seem to be supported with Apple maps. The code below does work on Android devices but not iOS and Window Phone.

```
https://www.google.co.uk/maps/dir/Current+Location/LAT,LONG,LAT,LONG
```

Is there any way to make this happen on iOS, Android and Window Phone devices?

Edit: I need to native map apps to launch as this seems to be the only way to show the navigation (sat-nav like) maps.

Answer (score 0):

searched the web, looks like its not supported on iOS

http://www.macworld.com/article/2687984/how-to-create-multi-destination-map-routes-on-your-iphone.html

Comment: I found the same thing but just wanted to double check I hadn't missed a way around this. Thanks though.